# Do you have to change the background image every second?

Tags: c#

i just started learning c# two month ago, and i got this code for my current project (windows forms) to set the background image:

```
    public FormMain()
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image;
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new Timer();
        ////change the background image every second  
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add image in list from resource file.  
        List<Bitmap> lisimage = new List<Bitmap>();
        lisimage.Add(Properties.Resources.image);
        var indexbackimage = DateTime.Now.Second % lisimage.Count;
        this.BackgroundImage = lisimage[indexbackimage];
    }
```

my question is: do you have to change the background image every second, or is it enough if i just write (i have only one single background image):

```
public FormMain()
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

cause it seems to work.

Comment: If you only have one image, just set it one time. The first code has a bunch of images it cycles through.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp But the first code always adds `Properties.Resources.image` to the list, meaning it's a list of just that one image!

Comment: @Shaamaan The code doesn't make much sense to me either. Assuming there's something else not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only need a timer like that if you were iterating through a series of images in order to create an animation.

What you have is good enough for setting the image once.

Answer (score 1):

As AaronLS wrote, setting the background once would suffice. I'd go a step further and explain why the extra code you have makes very little sense (assuming this is the entire code).

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add image in list from resource file.  
    List<Bitmap> lisimage = new List<Bitmap>(); //this line creates a new list
    lisimage.Add(Properties.Resources.image); //fill the NEWLY created list with the one image from the resources
    //note, that resources are usually static, so it's always the same resource
    var indexbackimage = DateTime.Now.Second % lisimage.Count; //choose an index from the list, but the list only contains that one image, so the index will always be 0
    this.BackgroundImage = lisimage[indexbackimage]; //pick the same image that was set initially
}
```

As you can see, the code is rather nonsensical - it doesn't DO anything. It SEEMS someone wanted to create a mechanism to switch images every second, but even THAT is poorly coded.

Comment: I noticed that as well, I wondered if this was incorrectly adapted from an example that originally had a list of images and it was iterating through them.  The modulus operator is a clear give away of going back to the beginning of the list to replay the animation.